# Measure flowpath length from a point

Tags: qgis, flow, flow-direction

[image: Output from WBT "tracedownslopeflowpaths"]I am using QGIS 3.28.2-Firenze. I have am using WBT "tracedownslopeflowpaths" to establish flowpath from a 3D scalar point (numbered points in image).  How do I set a measured distance (1320 feet) from each 3D scalar point?

Comment: Is it a single line? Including a screenshot of your current situation would help readers understand your question better. Take a look at the `$length` or `length()` functions in the field calculator to determine the length. The `line_substring` function using `(0, 1500)` as arguments will give you the first 1500 feet of the line (provided your layer CRS is in feet).

Comment: Multiple lines coming from different vector points.  I want to measure from each vector point.  I've used the calculator only a few times, so I'll research using those functions.  I'll try to post a screenshot.  Thank you.

Comment: Matt, I'm not sure how to write that expression to measure the length.  I've fumbled with different expressions.  Is there somewhere I can look to learn how to write it?  Thank you.